# benefits of xinetd for a web server

Tags: web-application, linux, webserver

What are the pros and cons of using xinetd for a web server running on a VPS. Assume the following measures have already been taken to secure the system:

- system hardening, latest updates, minimal packages
- strick iptables firewall
- controlled/limited use of admin privileges
- properly configured services
- hardened web application
- web application firewall
- continuous vulnerability assessments
- log monitoring

Comment: do you know what xinetd is for? your question is like: what are the pros and cons of a brown sofa when installing an alarm-device from company Foo

Comment: do tell what xinetd is used for on modern day production Linux server?

Comment: nagios-nrpe, (mostly custom) services that doesnt have any limitiation build-in AND where iptables-access for those who administer these services is not wanted. xinted is just a tcpwrapper, not a service itself. http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/11/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-TCP_Wrappers_and_xinetd.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link. I've been experimenting w/ using xinetd w/ SSH and I'm not really seeing any benefits it provides.Is is true that xinetd is being fazed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting an `xinetd` server in front of your web server will reduce security: in addition to any security holes in the web server, you now also are vulnerable to any security holes in `xinetd`.  Any security measures you can apply through `xinetd`, you can apply instead through the firewall or the web server.